# Creating upgrade patch for database installer using visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I have used visual studio(vs2010) installer to restore a database backup file to the target server.

Now my requirement is to create a patch that will update the database if required.These updates may be in form of addition of scripts etc.

If i will again take the updated .bak file and restore it on target server through installer,the existing data will be lost that client is using.

So i just want to create a patch which will install the newer changes only, say addition of new table in the database.

Please suggest way to do it.

Regards,

Shipra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Somewhere in your database, store a version number.
2. When your program is run, check the version number in the database.
3. If the version number is not sufficient (e.g. version 3.0 is found but 3.1 is required), execute the SQL commands that update the database to the required version (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, ...)

That way, all you need to do is update your program. Yes, this means that you have to keep track of changes to your database schema. (Note that this solution requires that the user running the program has schema modification rights to the database.)

Comment: I have only .bak file included in my setup project.So i can't add version information here.How can i run the setup project to install only the changes in the database.

Comment: @Shipu: You can't make the setup project install only the changes in the database. That feature is not supported by Visual Studio. You need to either use a third-party tool for that or implement a solution yourself. My answer outlines such a solution.